# Unity Instantiate with transform position?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I know this is second time i ask this kind of question but i have no solution for this. Ok this is my code:

```
public GameObject ball;
public GameObject Mycamera;
GameObject mainplayer;
private void Update()
{
mainplayer= Instantiate(ball, playerspawpoint.position, playerspawpoint.rotation); 

    float horizon = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");


    Mycamera.transform.RotateAround(mainplayer.transform.position,new Vector3(0,mainplayer.transform.position.y,0) ,10 * Time.deltaTime*horizon);
}
```

Ok, my main purpose is making camera move around the ball that has instantiated. But when i hit <- or -> it just move around somewhere very far away and i have tried alot of different ways, no succeed. Please help me

Comment: If you put your `Instantiate()` in your `Update()` method, this will happen every frame again and again. Also you are moving the camera way to fast with `10 * Time.deltaTime * horizon`. Try to decouple ball movement and camera movement. Move the Ball and let the camera follow (with it's own script). These are mostly basic things which you can find on the Unity3D Tutorial Page, which i honestly recommend you. https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials

Comment: Thankyou, well actually i have long code that just instantiate the ball 1 time but i compacted it easier to question.

Answer (score -1):

Can you call the `Instantiate()` in the `Start()` method.
suggestion:

```
  mainplayer= Instantiate(ball, playerspawpoint.position, playerspawpoint.rotation) as Gameobject;
```